# Is it good practice to prototype a JavaScript 'equals' method for custom object declarations, and if so how?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I'm trying to create a set of re-usable objects in javascript and some of the managed-framework paradigms (like .NET) don't directly translate.

For instance, there is no global `getType()` method or its equivalent, and there is no default `equals()` prototype function on Object that even just does a basic reference comparison.

So if I was going to go about creating object definitions, what is the best way to write the comparison function prototype?

e.g. if I started along the lines of the below, am I headed in the right direction or setting myself up for some pain later?

EDIT: Placed code on same line as return as per comment suggestion

```
function Car(make, model, colour) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
}

Car.prototype.equals = function(otherCar) {
    // Check that 'otherCar' really is a 'Car' ?
    // otherwise the property comparison code below with throw an exception, right?
    // How?


    // I could just use try / catch, but that could be 'expensive'?

    // Property-for-property comparison


    try {

        return this.make === otherCar.make
            && this.model === otherCar.model
            && this.colour === otherCar.colour;

    } catch(err) {

        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Is it right do you create a prototype for the function? Or how to properly implement the method equals() for real class-function Car?

Comment: OT: Put `this.make === otherCar.make` on the same line as `return`. Otherwise JS will insert a semicolon after `return` and the function will return `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks @Felix did not know that (haven't been burned by that mistake recently anyway)

Comment: @Andrew I would say both - is it good practice to add a comparison method for your own objects. And then if it is, best-practice / conventions for doing it. As with most code, when many people working on it you want to make it easier by having everyone preferably doing it a similar way.

Comment: I dont know about best practice, but: if _car1=new Car("a","b","c");car2=new Car("a","b","c");_ then _car1.equals(car2)===true_. Then if _car2.xxx=123_: car1 is stay equals to car2 or not? Only your private logic can select right way. Additionally you can make some checks: _otherCar instanceof Car_ or _Object.getPrototypeOf(otherCar)===Car.prototype_ regarding of your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `try-catch` is not necessary here. The return statement does not throw an Exception anyway. Just use

```
    return otherCar !== null &&
        this.make === otherCar.make
        && this.model === otherCar.model
        && this.colour === otherCar.colour;
```

It will always return a boolean value unless you don't pass anything in the first place. If, however, you wish to have the function return false without any parameters, use

```
    return typeof otherCar !== 'undefined' &&
        otherCar !== null &&
        this.make === otherCar.make
        && this.model === otherCar.model
        && this.colour === otherCar.colour;
```

As for the general idea, I think it's not bad and if you have a lot of comparisons to make. This confines you back into tight frames which depending on reasons might be good, but at the same time you sacrifice freedom.

**EDIT** `try-catch` block was partially fixed in the question. Added improvements pointed out in comments.

Comment: Try-catch can be needed if _otherCar_ is not an _object_.

Comment: This will return `undefined`. JS will insert a semicolon after `return`.

Comment: @andrew Well, pretty much everything in Javascript is an object. I could only think of `null` throwing an error. I've added a caparison for that case as well. Are there any other ones I can't remember right now?

Comment: @gilden Not only _null_. Also _undefined_ (calling without parameters)

Comment: @andrew Agreed, but calling without parameters typically points to the programmer forgetting to pass anything. I most certainly wouldn't want the `equals` function to silently return false leaving me clueless to why my code is not working as intended.

Comment: @gilden. not only without parameters, but and with one parameters with _(void 0)_ value.